# ADODB record set throwing an error when a sql query with a UNION is passed

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I have something similer to the following code. It keeps on throwing me an error stating

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6'

Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Open'

Could the UNION be the issue. Please help!

//Connection string included

```
<%
SQL = "(SELECT a as id , b as url FROM tbl_a) UNION (SELECT c as id , d as url FROM tbl_b )"

rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open sql,objConn,3,3

if not rs.eof then

    do while not rs.eof
        response.Write(rs("url") & "<br/>")
        rs.movenext
    loop
else
    Response.Write("not found")

end if
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Set statement when creating the recordset object

```
Set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

Comment: Thank you AardVark. can't imagene I missed that